# Adding ui-bootstrap is getting error

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

when I trying to add ui_bootstrap it throws error it gives the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).controller(...).directive(...).directive(...).animation is not a function
```

What could be the problem, I have not added any code yet

html head

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <script src='{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}'></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/angular.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/ui_bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/controllers.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/cookies.js' %}"></script>
</head>
```

What could be the issue.....seems strange for me....When I remove ui_bootstrap.js link the error goes off

app.js

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/static/views/home.html',
                controller: 'index_ctrl'
            })
            .when('/:id', {
                templateUrl: '/static/views/detail.html',
                controller: 'detail_ctrl'
            })
    }
])

sampleApp.filter('cut', function () {
        return function (value, wordwise, max, tail) {
            if (!value) return '';

            max = parseInt(max, 10);
            if (!max) return value;
            if (value.length <= max) return value;

            value = value.substr(0, max);
            if (wordwise) {
                var lastspace = value.lastIndexOf(' ');
                if (lastspace != -1) {
                    value = value.substr(0, lastspace);
                }
            }

            return value + (tail || ' …');
        };
    });
```

Any help is appreciated................

Answer (score 1):

I assume that ui-bootstrap is injected into module in app.js.  If so, move the app.js script tag after the ui-bootstrap.js tag.

Comment: Can you update your post to include your module declaration from app.js?

Comment: Ok.  Move cookies.js tag above app.js tag.

Comment: @jbrown...did not help...I removed cookies...still same issues

Comment: Not sure if its related but your syntax on your jquery include should be   <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>

Comment: That's possible.  What version of ui-bootstrap are you using?  Even the older versions of ui-bootstrap require angular 1.2.x

Comment: Its the newer version 1.2.5

Comment: Ok, so you're going to need angular 1.4.x or higher